# handling data in jFormattedTextField

Tags: swing

I have jFormatted field with name "jFormattedTextField3" in First.java file.
the value in this field must display in jFormattedTextFieldNoOfWorkers in Second.java file.

how can i handle the data and display in jFormattedTextFieldNoOfWorkers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check lots of examples:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AquickdemonstrationofJFormattedTextField.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice, thorough explanation in one of Java SE tutorial on [Formatted Text Fields](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html#value).